# Incorrect Relative call address for 32/16bit bootloader compiled using gcc/ld for x86

Tags: gcc, x86, nasm, ld, bootloader

This question is similar to [Incorrect relative address using GNU LD w/ 16-bit x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61446278/incorrect-relative-address-using-gnu-ld-w-16-bit-x86), but I could not solve by building a cross-compiler.

The scenario is, I have a second stage bootloader that starts as 16bit, and brings itself up to 32 bit. As a result, I have mixed assembly and C code with 32 and 16 bit code mixed together.

I have included an assembly file which defines a global that I will call from C, basically with the purpose of dropping back to REAL mode to perform BIOS interrupts from the protected mode C environment on demand. So far, the function doesn't do anything except get called, push and pop some registers, and return:

```
[bits 32]
BIOS_Interrupt:
PUSHF
...
ret
global BIOS_Interrupt
```

this is included in my main bootloader.asm file that is loaded by the stage 1 mbr.

In C, I have defined:

```
extern void BIOS_Interrupt(uint32_t intno, uint32_t ax, uint32_t bx, uint32_t cx, uint32_t dx, uint32_t es, uint32_t ds, uint32_t di, uint32_t si);
```

in a header, and

```
BIOS_Interrupt(0x15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
```

in code, just to test calling

I can see in the resultant disassembled linked binary that the call is invariably set 2 bytes too low in RAM:

```
00000132  0100              add [bx+si],ax
00000134  009CFA9D          add [si-0x6206],bl
00000138  6650              push eax
0000013A  6653              push ebx
...
00001625  6A00              push byte +0x0
00001627  6A00              push byte +0x0
00001629  6A00              push byte +0x0
0000162B  6A00              push byte +0x0
0000162D  6A00              push byte +0x0
0000162F  6A00              push byte +0x0
00001631  6A00              push byte +0x0
00001633  6A00              push byte +0x0
00001635  6A15              push byte +0x15
00001637  E8F9EA            call 0x133
```

The instruction at 135 should be the first instruction reached (0x9C = PUSHF), but the call is for 2 bytes less in memory at 133, causing runtime errors.

I have noticed that by using the NASM .align keyword, the extra NOPs that are generated do compensate for the incorrect relative address.

Is this an issue with the linking process? I have LD running with -melf_i386, NASM with -f elf and GCC with -m32 -ffreestanding -0s -fno-pie -nostdlib

edit: images added for @MichaelPetch. Code is loaded at 0x9000 by MBR. Interestingly, the call shows a correct relative jump, to 0x135, but the executing disassembly at 0x135 looks like the code at 0x133 (0x00, 0x00).

Bochs about to `call BIOS_Interrupt`
[image: screenshot of Bochs about to call BIOS_Interrupt]

Bochs at `call start`
[image: screenshot of Bochs at call start]

edit 2: correction to image 2 after refreshing memdump after call

[memdump and dissasembly after calling BIOS_Interrupt (call 0x135)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h4F8.png)

Comment: It really sounds like the code that is calling the function may have the wrong bitness (16 instead of 32 maybe) and it has computed the wrong distance to the function (off by 2). If you had a complete project it might help, but I'd use BOCHS to step through the code and see what is happening.

Comment: I can see in disassembly what is going on re. the code. The code seems to be working fine, it's the linker/compiler that's causing the issue. The code does mix 16 and 32 bit instructions, via use of the [bits 16/32] directive in NASM.

Comment: What tool chain are you using? A cross compiler? A native compiler for Windows? A native compiler for Linux? etc? In a case like this I would use BOCHS to step through the code and see what instructions are actually being executed (including the call). BOCHS will show the decoding for the mode the processor is in (something simple disassembly will not tell you). I have some non generic code that does the switch here to do an int 0x10: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41731180/3857942

Comment: I assume not a cross compiler from the question and possibly a Linux tool chain since your linker supports ELF although the latter assumption may not be true.

Comment: I'm using GCC and binutils on Ubuntu. The other question I linked seemed similar to my issue, so I followed the advice and compiled GCC and binutils according to https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler , which I'm using now but to no avail. I'll try to get BOCHS working. Looking at the link you sent, I ran NASM with the same parameters on my assembly file and ran objdump with the same parameters, and in the output did not see any info for relocation for the label: `00000135 <BIOS_Interrupt>:
[bits 32]
BIOS_Interrupt:
    pushf
 135: 9c                    pushf  `

Comment: @MichaelPetch see edit for Bochs debugging. I am possibly more confused now than before :/

Comment: In your NASM source code are you using section directives with things like vstart options? Are you loading the code into memory properly?

Comment: No vstart directives, no explicit sections at all for asm in fact, just using the nasm default .text when linking. Linker has a start of 0x9000, and the binary seems to load properly when doing previous testing and development. Just uses an int 0x13 to read the first x sectors to 0x900:0x0000 and then jumps to this location. Every other instruction executes fine, including transition to protected mode and general 32-bit C code execution.

Comment: Have you verified everything in memory from 0x9000 onward is in the place it should be? Is there any chance you may have loaded this data/code at the wrong address? Maybe it worked in one situation and the code broke for this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by check, but comparing the assembly source to disassembly and the disassembly and memdump in Bochs, everything seems in place. Immediately before the BIOS_Interrupt.asm file, I have included another .asm file which ends with a define dd 0x100, which matches with the 4 bytes prior to 0x135 (0,1,0,0), so it seems valid there. Just realised I did not refresh memdump after calling, and it seems that the memory values have changed after calling (adding in additional edit shortly)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Okay I've figured out my issue and it was a rookie mistake. Thanks for your help and I'll post what the issue was as far as I can tell. Apologies for wasting your time here, but thanks for your help and recommendations of Bochs, it really helped narrow it down

Comment: No problem.  Glad you found the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks again to @MichaelPetch for giving me a few pointers.

I don't think there is an issue with the linker, and that the dissassembly was "tricking" me, in that the combination of 16 and 32 bit code led to inaccurate code.

In the end, it was due to overriding of memory values from prior operations. In the code immediately before the BIOS_Interrupt label, I had defined a dword, dd IDT_REAL, designed to store the IDT for real mode processing. However, I did not realise (or forgot) that the SIDT/LIDT instructions take 6 bytes of data, so when I was calling SIDT, it was overriding the first 2 bytes of the label's location in RAM, resulting in runtime errors. After increasing the size of the variable from dword to qword, I can run just fine w/o error.

The linker/compiler suggestion seems to be a red-herring that I fell for courtesy of objdump. However, I've at least learned from this the benefits of Bochs and double checking code before jumping to conclusions!

Comment: You only actually need 6 bytes there; `resb 6` or `dd 0` / `dw 0` or `dw 0,0,0` or anything equivalent.  (If you want other vars to be aligned and you don't have anything to fill the padding with, then sure qword).